# A program that checks which number is bigger

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I'm studying assembly (8086) and we learned about jumps and we were told to write a program that will get 2 numbers from 2 memory cells and will put the bigger one in another memory cell.
So I wrote:

```
mov al,[0]
mov bl,[1]
cmp al,bl
js eq
jns noteq
eq:
    mov [10h],bl
    jmp end
noteq:
    mov [10h],al
    jmp end
end:
    hlt
```

But I was told it won't work because I need to change the `js` and `jns` to `jc` and `jnc` in case both of the numbers are negative but when I ran it on an emulator it worked both ways. Who's right? Me or the teacher, or maybe both of our ways will work either way? If you say the teacher please explain why, because the teacher couldn't.

EDIT: We could only use `JC` `JNC` `JZ` `JNZ` `JS` `JNS`

Comment: Regardless of that, that `js eq` is pointless. Either `jns noteq` jumps to `noteq`, or it doesn't and execution continues at `eq:`.

Comment: @Michael I know it is I just preferred to be organized with it to make sure I'm not wrong

Comment: More redundant code isn't "organized", it's just distracting.  And to an experienced eye, looks possibly wrong, makes the reader wonder why there are 2 branches and where they both go, and to sort the logic out.  The 2nd `jmp end` is also pointless.  An idiomatic if/else is a conditional jump over the `if` body, which ends with a `jmp` over the else part.  So 2 jump instructions total, only one of them conditional.  Here you could just do one `jcc` over a `mov al, bl`, then store `al`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number must be unsigned because you can't do properly do signed compare without also checking OF (to get the right answer in cases where the subtraction has signed overflow, e.g. on AL=127, BL=-1).

Therefore you need to use `jb` (unsigned below), aka `jc`.  Talking about "negative" numbers is confusing the issue; they  actually want you to do an unsigned compare.  But yes the case where your code is buggy is when the numbers are different by 128 or more, like 10 < 222, so the MSB of `al-bl` (which goes into SF, the sign bit) is not the condition you're looking for.  i.e. it's different from the carry-out (borrow) in CF.

Note that JL (signed less-than) is `SF ≠ OF` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc).

See also http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt re: signed overflow vs. carry-out.